# RegEx for matching specific numeric patterns

Tags: regex, perl, grep, regex-lookarounds, regex-group

I want to match numbers without signs or operator, So I came up this regex.

```
echo "-123 +1234" | grep -Po '(?<=-)123 (?<=\+)1234'
```

but it's not matching the string. Why two lookbehind not working? If I do

```
echo "-123 +1234" | grep -Po '(?<=-)123
```

I get the correct result `123` but when I do `grep -Po '(?<=-)123 (?<=\+)1234'` the second part is not matching.

My desired result:

```
123 1234
```

Comment: Lookaround does not consume characters - you're not consuming the `+` before the `1234`. Did you want `(?<=-)123 \+1234`?

Comment: in that case I am getting `+` in my output, `123 +1234` I don't want the signs to be included in my final result

Comment: If your string is always signs followed by digits, you can simply use `[+-](\d+)` and take only captured group

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In regex patterns, `ab` means `a` followed by `b`, which is another way of saying `b` preceded by `a`. Don't forget that `(?<=...)` matches zero characters from the perspective of the surrounding pattern, so it's as if it wasn't there from the point of view of the surrounding pattern. This means that `(?<=-)123 (?<=\+)1234` will match a subset of what `123 1234` matches. It's of particular interest that the pattern will only match if `1234` is preceded by a space.

The subset of strings that match are those where `123` is preceded by a `-` (thanks to `(?<=-)`) and `1234` is preceded by a `+` (thanks to `(?<=\+)`). It's of particular interest that the pattern will only match if `1234` is preceded by a `+`.

Since `(?<=-)123 (?<=\+)1234` will only match if `1234` is preceded by a space and preceded by a `+`, it will never match.

It's not clear what you want.

Maybe you want this?

```
$ echo "-123 +1234" | grep -Po '\d+'
123
1234
```

Maybe you want this?

```
$ echo "-123 +1234" | perl -nle'@m=/\d+/g; print "@m" if @m'
123 1234
```

Maybe you want this?

```
$ echo "-123 +1234" | perl -nle'print "$1 $2" if /-(\d+) \+(\d+)/'
123 1234
```

Comment: I did not get `is preceded by a space and preceded by a +` Where did I specify that I want this to be preceded by space?

Comment: I added clarification to the question

Answer (score 1):

It may be that you want to just match numbers

```
echo "-123 +1234" | perl -wnE'@m = /([0-9]+)/g; say for @m'
```

unless you'd like to match numbers *only if they come with signs*, in which case

```
echo "-123 +1234" | perl -wnE'@m = /(?<=[+-])([0-9]+)/g; say for @m'
```

or just

```
echo "-123 +1234" | perl -wnE'@m = /[+-]([0-9]+)/g; say for @m'
```

in which case the `+` or `-` are consumed.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to extract the numbers that are preceded by a `-` or a `+`, then you can use:

```
echo '-123 +1234 456' | grep -oP '(?<=-|\+)\d+'
123
1234
```

If you just want to extract any sequence of digits *(that is a word by itself)*, then using grep in `perl` like regex is not required and you can simply use:

```
 echo '-123 +1234 456' | grep -Eo '\b[0-9]+\b'
```